# why does accessing C++ string class through string.h work?

Tags: c++

In the C++ program below, I include the string.h file and I successfully instantiate the C++ string class in it and call one of its member functions: size().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    string s = "Hello";
    cout << "String: " << s << endl;
    cout << "Size of string: " << s.size() << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;    
}
```

The output is:

```
String: Hello
Size of string: 5
```

I am using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

My question: doesn't the string.h file just provide the functions for manipulating C strings? It doesn't include the definition of the C++ string class right? So, how is it that I am able to access the C++ string class without using `#include <string>`? My understanding is that the string.h file is the C strings library file and `<string>` includes the C++ string library file. Is this not right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `std::string` is defined though one of the files included in the `<iostream>` header. The streams provide support for input and output of strings, so they need to include a string header in order to define the corresponding `>>` and `<<` operations.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. BTW, what is the file that corresponds to `<string>`? I mean, what is the corresponding file's name and extension?

Comment: @GigaRohan This is system dependent: on my system (OS X w/gcc compiler) the file included from `<iostream>` is `bits/stringfwd.h`. It is included indirectly, through a chain of `istream` -> `ios` -> `iosfwd`.

Comment: The standard does not require it to be a file, but on my mac it's just  `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string`. No extension.

Comment: Note that this is not 100% reliable. For starters, `<iostream>` just contains `std::cin/cout/cerr/clog`. `<<` comes from `<ostream>` and `>>` comes from `<istream>`. Even if `<iostream>` included those, it is still possible that `<istream>` uses compiler magic to define `>>` without including `<string>`

Comment: Wouldn't it be more _natural_ if stream `<<` and `>>` overloads for strings were defined in `<string>` itself?

Comment: @Hindol There's a chicken-and-egg problem with both approaches: in this case, `string` would need to include headers of `istream` and `ostream`.